# Issue applying textblob to a dataframe series

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

After splitting my dataset into train, test, and validation sets I have a `x_validation` set which is a set of strings. Calling `x_validation.head()` gives:

```
0    this drink is making my throat hurt more and need to convince corey to go to jacks mannequin concert obvs will be in need of advil
1                         there gonna be movie on no can see it not even the trailers hate thinking about it as it is ll have breakdown
2                                                 the wire on my braces is too long and is cutting through my cheek farrrrrrrk it hurts
3                                             finally have uploaded my documentary to an external site message me for link and password
4                                        lovely national day today hour children parade and hour citizens parade with ju jitsu training
```

It has something like 15,000 strings total. I'm trying to create a new list `tbresult` containing the sentiment polarity scores of each string as calculated by TextBlob:

```
tbresult = [TextBlob(i).sentiment.polarity for i in x_validation]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>
```

I'm confused because when I do the following,

```
lst = [x for x in x_validation]
TextBlob(lst[0]).sentiment.polarity
```

it works, I get 0.5. I'm confused where this float type is coming from in the error. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove rows contains a float value, or use `.isna().sum()` rather than using `dropna`.

```
def remove_floats(row):
  if isinstance(row, str):
    return row
  else:
    return None
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['balh_1', 'blah_2', 1.0, 'blah_3']})

for key in df:
  df[key] = df[key].apply(remove_floats)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

df
```

---

```
     col
0   balh_1
1   blah_2
3   blah_3
```

Comment: Appreciate it. I did this, as well as x_validation.to_frame(), then x_validation.applymap(str). I then used your function for good measure, though when I called x_validation.dropna, it didn't appear to remove anything. Either way, things work! Thanks for your help.